# how to access value in another object using yup by key (trying to use .when('key'))

Tags: reactjs, formik, yup

```
yup.object({
  personInfo: yup.object({
    customerType: yup.string().required(i18next.t("This field is mandatory"))
  }),
  orgInfo: yup.object({
    companyName: yup.string().when("personInfo.customerType", {
      is: customerType => customerType !== CustomerTypes.STAFF,
      then: yup
        .string()
        .required("This field is mandatory"),
      otherwise: yup.string()
    })
 })
})
```

I'm trying to validate companyName field using **when("key",...)** by field from another object "**personInfo.customerType**"

How can I access "personInfo.customerType" from "orgInfo.companyName" by **key** ? I noticed that I can access this field if both customerType and companyName are in the same object without any path like .when("customerType", ... )

This is an example of actual schema, so I can't change this schema easily so that "customerType" would be in one object with "companyName"